# Login times counter in php

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I have a database and i am trying to make login times count using php this is my code :

```
$GetLoginTimes = "Select Login_Times from usertable where email = '$email'";
$GetLoginTimes2 = mysqli_fetch_array($GetLoginTimes);
$LoginTimesEdited = $GetLoginTimes2 + 1;
$UpdateLastLogin = "UPDATE usertable SET Login_Times = '$LoginTimesEdited' WHERE email = '$email'";
mysqli_query($con, $UpdateLastLogin);
```

when i login the login_times is set to 1 but when i do it again it stays the same
TIA!

Comment: Use prepared statments or PDO to prevent [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1). I don't know how you validate `$email` but 1 mistake and your query is unsafe

Comment: How do i do that i am still new

Comment: I am using mysqli for everything but i don't know much about making my query safe so would you please explain it

Comment: I mean that for example i have mysqli_query and mysqli_fetch_array etc..

Comment: Al the explanation is in the link in my first comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Update = "UPDATE Users SET Last_Login = ?, Login_Times = Login_Times + 1 WHERE Users.Email = ?";
$stmt = $db->execute_query($Update, [$Date, $Email]);
```

This is the best way to achieve it i believe as it combines both queries so more efficient and is safe against SQL injections because it uses parameters and most importantly works fine!

Comment: HOW it is safe if you ARE NOT using **parameters** as you have been told **a dozen times** already?

Comment: I forgot to update it here but it is updated in the latest question i asked thanks for reminding me

Comment: @yourcommonsense when i answered it i forgot to put the updated version instead i put the old one but i totally understood the parameters point i even have it running now on my code and now i updated it in the answer too. (I just forgot to update the question when i understood the point) and as i said i used the new version when i asked another question yesterday as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/q/77108416/14967538 i was just too tired and didnt notice that i copied the wrong code here

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to retrieve the login count before updating it, update it in one request like that :

```
$UpdateLastLogin = "UPDATE usertable SET login_times = login_times + 1 where email  = '$email'";
mysqli_query($con, $UpdateLastLogin);
```

Comment: Thank You! Sorry i am still new

Answer (score 1):

the problem in your code is you didn't use $result in the right way
besides, to prevent `SQL injection` you should use the `prepare statement` here is your example with `prepare statement`:

```
$email = "example@example.com";
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE usertable SET Login_Times= Login_Times + 1 where email=?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
$stmt->execute();
```