# What is the difference between execute_query and prepare+execute?

Tags: php, mysqli

What is the difference between using `execute_query()`[1] or using the `prepare()` then `execute()` [2] and when do we use the bind parameter and why? Like in example [2] we already gave the variables within the execute so when is the bind parameter more useful?

[1]

```
$stmt = $db->execute_query($Update, [$Date, $Email]);
```

[2]

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO Users (Username, Email, Password, Creation_Date, VIP, Admin) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->execute([
    $Username, 
    $Email,
    $Password,
    $Creation_date,
    $VIP,
    $Admin,
]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`execute_query()` is the simplest of them all. It prepares and executes the query, and returns a `mysqli_result` object or bool. It can be used if all you want to do is execute a simple query and get the results.

`prepare()` returns a `mysqli_stmt` object which you can execute at your own convenience. It's more robust than the previous option. It is useful, for example, when executing the same prepared statement within a loop with different values.

You can pass all params as an array to either `execute()` or `execute_query()`, but if you want more robustness, you can bind variables by reference to the statement object using `bind_param()`. There are not many uses for it, but it's there if you need it. It was also the only option available until PHP 8.1.

Answer (score 4):

`execute_query()` is simply a shortcut that allows you to combine `prepare()`, `bind_param()`, `execute()`, and `get_result()` into a single call.

Since you don't have a `mysqli_stmt` object, status information about the query will be put into the `$db` object. For example, instead of `$stmt->affected_rows` you use `$db->affected_rows`.